# Realm Not Working with Packaged Electron App

Tags: node.js, electron, realm

I've started the Realm-provided realm-electron-advanced-quickstart found [here](https://github.com/mongodb-university/realm-electron-advanced-quickstart).

Everything works fine when running in dev, but when I package this with [electron-builder](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder), the app does not work. I moved `createWindow()` to the top of the `app.whenReady()` function so I could see the debugger, and it showed the following message:

```
Failed to open realm: Error: illegal operation on a directory
    at run (renderer.js:26)
    at renderer.js:39
```

Line 26 is

```
const realm = new Realm(config);
```

I suspect this is some sort of path/permissions issue with the .realm file.

In `main.js`, I changed the path in the realm config to

```
path.join(app.getPath("home"),"my.realm")
```

But I could not do so on `renderer.js`.

I would appreciate any ideas or examples of how this has been implemented before.

I'm running Node v14.15.4.